# A dplyr function that yields the reciprocal of a number

Tags: r, dplyr

When using dplyr, is there a function such that:

```
Reciprocal <- 1:5 %>% 
   reciprocalfunction()

Reciprocal
```

the desired result being:

```
[1] 1.0000000 0.5000000 0.3333333 0.2500000 0.2000000
```

Comment: with `R>4.1`, you could do `1:5 %>% (\(x) 1/x)`

Answer (score 1):

`dplyr` normally works on dataframes but it's simple enough to do

```
data.frame(a = 1:5) %>% mutate(a = 1/a)
```

```
          a
1 1.0000000
2 0.5000000
3 0.3333333
4 0.2500000
5 0.2000000
```

Or just define a custom function:

```
r_p = function(x) 1 / x

1:5 %>% r_p
[1] 1.0000000 0.5000000 0.3333333 0.2500000 0.2000000
```

Answer (score 1):

The pipe symbol `%>%` originated in the magrittr package, which has the function `divide_by` to avoid having to define your own division operator for use in the pipe.

```r
library(magrittr)

1:5 %>% divide_by(1, .)
#> [1] 1.0000000 0.5000000 0.3333333 0.2500000 0.2000000
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the function form of `^` operator:

```
library(magrittr)

1:5 %>% `^`(-1)
[1] 1.0000000 0.5000000 0.3333333 0.2500000 0.2000000
```